# Log for WiFi on Android Tablet

Tags: wi-fi

Is there a log that records WiFi connectivity events/issues? I keep getting disconnected when using my Nexus 10 tablet and other devices on the same network do not.

Comment: Can you confirm if the Wifi MAC address is unique? And that it is added into the Wifi Router's mac filter list?

Comment: It is better not to ask question this way on Android Enthousiast. Because it is considered Off-Topic if you ask for app recommendations (see [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)). It is maybe better to explain the issues you are having, so the reason why you need the logs.

Answer (score 3):

There are several applications available that will read the log. In Android there is only one major log, where everything is written to.

Per application a different Tag is used in the log. So to find out information about the WiFi, you have to find out what the exact tag is. That way you can filter out all these messages, for me it was something like "WiFiStateMachine" for WiFi.

Next to the application mentioned by [Abhishek Sha](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/14568/abhishek-sha) ([Log Collector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector)), there is also [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat). I have used this application multiple times, and always helped me to find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can take

```
"adb shell logcat"
```

contains wpa_supplicant related logs. Wpa_supplicant is an open source application which is used in android phones to connect and manage Wi-Fi connections.This would help your disconnect issue.
or

```
"adb shell cat /proc/kmsg"
```

which is the file where kernel dumps the logs.here you can see Wi-Fi crash related logs.

Answer (score 0):

The [Log Collector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtralogic.android.logcollector) app grabs the Android system log. It should include information about anything interesting (errors, information, debug stuff) that happened to your phone in the last few minutes. You should give you the option to email the log to somewhere (yourself would be good).

Word of advice: I see that you're new here. I would advice that you do not ask for app recommendations as I have had issues in the past and my question was closed.